# Confusion regarding the range of a mapping

Tags: functions, notation

I have recently read the following statement which I do not understand:

> Each function $w\mapsto h(x,w)$ has range $Y$.

As far as I understand "$\mapsto$" denotes a mapping. How are they defining the function(s)? Is there a function for each $w$, and each of these functions has the same range?

Comment: $x$ must be fixed.  Then $f(w)=h(x,w)$ defines a function $f$ of one variable.

Comment: Close: there is a function **for each $x$**, not $w$, and each function has the same range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each fixed $x$ there is a function $f_x$ with variable $w$ defined as $f_x(w)=h(x,w)$.

The statement then says that $\forall x,x': \operatorname{ran}(f_x) = \operatorname{ran}(f_{x'})$.

Or in a more formal way:

$$\forall x,x': \forall w : \exists w': h(x,w)=h(x',w')$$

which comes down to the same thing.